# Using regular expressions to match repeating sequence

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to convert a TCL keyed list to a Java `HashMap` and need to use regular expressions to break pieces of the text out.  A sample of the text I am using is:

```
{ID {{NAME X } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226188  }}} {SRCID {{NAME XY } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226136  }}} {TYPE DATA }
```

Here there are three distinct groups ID, SRCID, and TYPE. I have tried using the regexp `{.*?}` but the first two groups get broken up.  If I use just `{.*}` then the whole string is matched as a unit, not three.  Any suggestions of what I should try next?

Comment: I don't think regular expression is the way to go in your case. You should rather be scanning each symbol of the string and if it's a curly brace, consider it as a new object (or part of the object).

Comment: You probably need to write simple recursive descent parser for this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_descent_parser

Comment: @MikhailVladimirov no you don't have to use parser.the input is **consistent** (*parathesis are balanced*).`regex` would do the job nicely..

Answer (score 0):

Here is sample code with regex to meet your requirement :

```
public class RegexTester {
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "{ID {{NAME X } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226188  }}} {SRCID {{NAME XY } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226136  }}} {TYPE DATA }";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(\\{\\bID.+\\})\\s*(\\{SRCID.+\\})\\s*(\\{TYPE DATA.+\\})");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(data);

    while (matcher.find()) {

        System.out.println(matcher.group(1)); // Group - ID
        System.out.println(matcher.group(2)); // Group - SRCID
        System.out.println(matcher.group(3)); // Group - TYPE DATA
    }
}
```

Output :

{ID {{NAME X } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226188  }}} 
{SRCID {{NAME XY } {HUB 0   } {NUM 14226136  }}} 
{TYPE DATA }

Hope this helps.